# Pycaret Model Performance Reducing after Hyper parameter tuning

Tags: data-science, automl, pycaret

I'm trying to train model using pycaret and noticed many times that Model performance reduces after Hyperparameter tuning.

I have attached an image showing how i'm trying to tuning.

Can any one suggest what i'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

[image]

Comment: I did not search through but yes, that's exactly what's happening with time series module as well!

Answer (score 0):

It also happened to me.After little search ,from documentation;

"In order to tune hyperparameters, the tune_model() function is used. This function automatically tunes the hyperparameters of a model on a pre-defined search space and scores it using stratified cross-validation."

So what i did, I used not only best model also 2nd and 3rd too. Incase some overfitting problems :).